# How to align vertical text horizontally center?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I have a vertical block of text that looks left-aligned like this:

```
T
e
x
t
```

See [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qq6LP/) for better visualisation.

How do I align it using CSS and without breaking up the text, so that the characters appear to be horizontally centered within the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letter spacing adds the space to the right of the letter. So you've to add equal padding to the left for imitating center alignment.

Apply `padding-left` equal to the `letter-spacing`

```
div {
width: 1em;
word-wrap: break-word;
margin:0 auto;
background: cyan;
letter-spacing:0.5em;
padding-left:0.5em;
text-align:center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qq6LP/10/)

**Update**

Visual appearance can be tweaked by simply changing the values…

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qq6LP/16/)

Comment: @QuestionOverflow you can adjust the visual appearance as you wish by changing the padding… http://jsfiddle.net/qq6LP/13/ the point is that letter-spacing adds spacing  to right, so you need to handle space on left..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qq6LP/14/ http://jsfiddle.net/qq6LP/15/ .. the answer can be tweaked anyway you want by changing the values..

Comment: @QuestionOverflow well like i said, the answer can be easily tweaked by simply changing the values.. http://jsfiddle.net/qq6LP/16/ :)

Comment: i think the key to centering here is letter-spacing. Must make it really small. The padding has no real purpose. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What about this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qq6LP/2/)?

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div>T</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>x</div>
    <div>t</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: cyan;
    width: 1em;
    line-height: 0.7em; 
    text-align:center
}
```

OR this one [**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/qq6LP/9/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    T<br>
    e<br>
    x<br>
    t<br>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: cyan;
    width: 1em;
    line-height: 0.7em; 
    text-align:center
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but one of the requirements is that the text must not be broken up. I need it for semantics and SEO purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qq6LP/1/)

```
div {
    background: cyan;
    width: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 1em;
    line-height: 0.7em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: No, I mean aligning the characters within the block, not aligning the block.

Answer (score 0):

try this {[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qq6LP/11/)}

```
div {
    background: cyan;
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 0.7em;
    text-align:center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding:0 10px
}
```

Comment: The width must be relative to the font-size as I need to cater for different styles.